# OneToOneField(user) imply recreating all account?

Tags: python, django

I extended user class with a new class "Profile" using OneToOneField. It worked but now I can't reuse old account. (So user,superuser and admin). I get a "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist" Error since my old account do not have any "Profile". I suppose their is an other way than recreating accounts (Because I can't imagine it in production every new version) but I can't figure out how to update every old account. Does someone has any clue?

Comment: How is it hard to figure out? Write a query to find all old accounts and write a `for` loop to create `Profile` for each of them, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some case, when you update your model(s), you have to write data migrations in addition to the schema migrations - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations for additional information

In your case, you should create a data migration to create Profile object for every existing user. Follow the example in the documentation - it is pretty good.

One important note - you CAN'T just import your Profile model in the migration. You must do it like that:

```
Profile = apps.get_model("yourappname", "Profile")
```